# Непонятная ошибка в коде от mypy

Tags: python, mypy

```
async def process_play_command(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Игра началась!\nЯ загадал число от 1 до 100!')
    users[message.from_user.id]['in_game'] = True
    users[message.from_user.id]['secret_number'] = randint(1, 100)
    print(type(users[message.from_user.id]['in_game']))
```

Есть такая функция. mypy находит ошибку в каждой переменной `message`:

> Item "None" of "Optional[User]" has no attribute "id"  [union-attr]mypy(error) (parameter) message: Message.

Пытался гуглить, практически никакой инфы по этому поводу не нашел, только один частный случай.

Comment: Поле `message.from_user` не заполнено, имеет значение `None`. Можно только проверить что пользователь не указан, и ничего не делать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что это поле заполняется из чата телеграмма и изначально элементарно заполнено быть не может :)

Comment: Факт состоит в том что вы получаете сообщения с пустым полем `from_user`. Тип этого поля `Optional[User]`. Что означает буквально "поле не обязательно, может быть не заполнено". Всё что знал, сказал.

Comment: Хорошо, это я понял. Но как, например, намеренно игнорировать эту ошибку, потому что она, по идее в сложившейся ситуации нерешима.

Comment: `if message.from_user is not None:`

Comment: Благодарю :) Теперь хоть как-то получится избегать этих красных подчеркиваний